# OS X Snow Leopard Desktop - removing a user login name and password for a share

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, login

I have a problem with one client machine on our network sometimes choosing to login to a share as "server" instead of as the user's name. The user is not making this choice. It appears the computer is defaulting to this whenever the user in the finder window, clicks on the server icon under "SHARED". The user then automatically logs in as "server".

Whenever we use the "Go" Menu and "Connect to Server..." we have used the user's login name and password and clicked "remember this password". But the user's login and password are not establishing themselves as the default.

So what plist file do I have to edit to fix this problem? I want to delete the server login information from this machine.

Yes, I have since changed the password for "server", but thats not the solution I am looking for. It seems that Macs have a really odd way of defaulting to a particular login/password for any given share, and it is very difficult to change this once established.

We have OS X 10.6 on our workstation desktops, and OS X Server 10.6 on our server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More likely than not you have a duplicate entry for the share in the users keychain, I'd start the search there.

Comment: Thanks. This was useful. I have since looked in the keychain to solve a number of these password problems.